# How can I send “text messages” from iPhone to Android with an email (not cellular) as the address?

Tags: iphone, email, text, android

Is there any way that would allow me to send a text message from my iPhone to someone who has an android phone. The person who has the android phone and doesn’t have a phone number but has an email address.

Is there a way for me to send a text message to the person’s android phone using their email in the same way that you’d use a phone number to send a text message?

Answer (score 1):

Most carriers in the US have email to text gateways.

As an example 5551111234@txt.att.net will send a text message to the phone with that number if it is on AT&T.

So in order to do what you trying to do you would need to know what carrier the intended recipient is on. Then you would need to know how you send an email as text, which you could easily find with a quick internet search.

Not being an Android user there **MAY** be a way to send an email as a text message so it is received in the Android equivalent of messages.app on iOS. But for the answer to that question you will need to look [elsewhere.](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to sending a text message like a SMS to someone else via an e-mail address, then the answer is usually **no**. Emails is usually not meant for this kind of use, but apparently at least in the US it may be possible. Check SteveChambers answer about that.

Your confusion most likely comes from Apples messages app, that allows you to send messages (similar to Telegram) to devices without a phone number. This, however, is restricted to Apple products like Macs and iPads.

The easiest and most obvious way for you to communicate would be via email. You have to have an email address configured in an email client (the preinstalled one on iOS is fine) and from there you can send an email to the recipient. However, the recipient needs a way of accessing their email, like an email client app or through a browser.